# Battery charging in enclosed space (garage)

Tags: battery, charging

I have a question regarding off-gassing of antique car batteries while charging.  If I have my batteries on constant charge with the tops off, would that cause enough sulfur discharge to corrode the receptacle terminals and cause copper wire tips to turn black? This is in a large, high ceiling, 2 car garage, in Southern Louisiana.  [image]

[image]

Comment: related reading: [Hazardous gases associated with lead-acid battery charging](http://goodforgas.com/hazardous-gases-associated-lead-acid-battery-charging-stations/) (mentions deteriorated and old batteris in the end of the article) and [Gases from car batteries](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17425/gases-from-car-batteries)

Comment: Are outlets in other locations (not garage) the same way? Or do you only see this in the garage?

Comment: CharlieRB. The affected outlets are only in the garage, which has doors and attached to home under same roof, but not conditioned.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like oxidation. That will happen just from being exposed to air over extended periods of time

Comment: and the moisture in the air...

Comment: yes, that also helps it along

Answer (score 0):

If copper is turning black in the atmosphere, the cause is very likely hydrogen sulfide ( H2S ) . Any chance of some leak from a nearby oil/gas well ? Although you should smell H2S at very low levels . Maybe a one time occurrence ? Copper is sort-of like silver; silver turns black due to H2S at such low levels it can't be smelled. I don't think a lead/acid battery has anything to do with it. In moist air copper will develop a blue/green patina ; a mix of hydroxides, carbonates and other stuff.